# How do I get NeutralinoJS working in Mac OS X?

Tags: neutralinojs

I just found NeutralinoJS for Mac which is awesome. I installed the Xcode command line tools and cmake before finding the real app on SourceForge. The only way I can get Neutralino to launch is if I swap app folders that are in the same folder as Neutralino. Does Neutralino have an interface for Mac? Also the terminal launches every time I use it. Is the terminal the debugger? Finally how do I create a Mac binary for distribution?

Answer (score 5):

I found out VS Code can do everything I need. Also I got rid of the Terminal launching by adding ".app" to the end of the Mac Binary. The features in NeutralinoJS are just what I need to create a game! So awesome!

Comment: Just renaming it with .app extention is enough? I am not able to get it working, can you help?

Comment: @sudharsantk I found using plain HTML files with JavaScript work best. Apple has gotten more and more restrictive so my idea for you may not work. A .app is really just a folder on Mac OS X. Try creating a folder for the binary file like this: _appnamehere_.app/Contents/MacOS/ _binaryfilehere_